# What are the factors that could make the theoretical frequency different from the measured frequency

Tags: doppler-effect

Measure the frequency of received ultrasound wave for velocities of the train and for both directions of motion

I'm trying to make a conclusion on my lab report but I would like to know what are the factors that could make the theoretical frequency different from the measured frequency

The measured frequency is measured using a counter installed Software for measurements and the theoretical frequency using the formula below f'

> c = 331.06 + 0.61t,   t = 23.8[C] ‘’ temperature of the lab’’
>
> f'=f * c/(c+-Vz)
>
> f  = 39023‘’stationary frequency’’ , Vz’’ speed of the
>   source(train)’’
>
> Theoretical Frequency [Hz] → 38996.7
>
> Measured Frequency [Hz] → 39000.4
>
> Theoretical Frequency[Hz] ← 39046.5
>
> Measured Frequency[Hz] ← 39042.2

Comment: How precise is your velocity measurement? How was it done? How precise is your temperature measurement? Would you trust it to be within 1 degree? Did you look at corrections for humidity? You are probably not required to if they didn't give you a formula.

Comment: the velocity was measured using Stationary microphone (receiver) and the Train(transmitter)  using installed Software for measurements , the temperature was measured in the lab and its accurate but didn't check for humidity , Does the humidity affect the velocity or frequency?

Comment: what are the errors?( in temperature, etc?)

Comment: Without knowing what the errors on the velocity and the temperature one can't tell.

Comment: the error of the thermometer used for measuring the temperature was 0.1[C ] but I could calculate the velocity error for → (V =0.0135)STANDARD ‘A’ TYPE UNCERTAINTIES because the error of the device was not given

Comment: Please edit the expanded information into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error for both directions is very similar - approximately 4 Hz - and with a consistent sign (measured frequency is 4 Hz closer to the actual source frequency than the "theoretical value").

From this I infer that most likely your velocity measurement is very poor, or the alignment of velocity vector and sound vector is very bad. If your microphone is not "directly in front of" the train, then the Doppler shift observed will be smaller - and this effect gets worse if you average the signal over a longer time (so the train gets closer to the microphone, and the angle error gets bigger). Without seeing your setup, it is hard to know if that is the source of your problem but I certainly would not rule it out.

You have an equation for the speed of sound $c$ which depends on $T$, the temperature (although you used $t$, I am pretty sure it's a function of temperature, not time). You give the temperature as 23.8 C. That implies an error of < 0.1 C in temperature, which would result in an error of < 0.06 m/s in the velocity; that is 0.02% of the value of ~331 m/s; and you can see that the size of the doppler shift directly relates to the error in the sound speed (there is a term $\frac{v}{c}$ which will scale with error in $v$ or $c$.)

You didn't specify how accurately you know the velocity of your train, or how well the source is aligned with the receiver (if your velocity is not quite directed straight at your sensor, it will affect the Doppler shift).

For this type of problem, you want to draw a diagram of the setup so you can see any source of geometrical error; and you want to do a simple error propagation to see how an error in one term will lead to an error in another term.

Comment: What do you mean by actual source frequency  (measured frequency is 4 Hz closer to the actual source frequency than the "theoretical value") ?

Comment: how did you know its closer

Comment: 39023 is center frequency. If you calculated 38996.7 and observed 39000.4, the observation is "inside" the interval [38996.7, 39023]. Similarly, when you calculated 39046.5 and observed 39042.2, the latter is in the interval [39023 39046.5]. So you observed a shift smaller than you expected - consistent with "the velocity is less than you thought". Which points to an error in the measurement of the velocity relative to the observer.

Comment: when i added or subtracted 0.1 to my temperature i got the measured frequency ← as 39049.3 , so is the error mostly from the temperauture

Comment: Only if you think the temperature changed between experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are 4 Hz, plus and minus.  If that was 1 sigma (standard deviation), that'd be 4 in 40000 approx, or 10^(-4). Check the specs for your counter, that may be somewhere around its accuracy.

It could also be a bias in the counter, since plus or minus numbers are symmetric.

Errors can be due also to the temperature measured (though 1 degree error should not make that difference, check if true or not, simply plug in 1 degree more or less in your theoretical formula). V is also probably not off by more than 1 mph, with a simple velocimeter. Try that sensitivity. So, you can try all of them.

Finally, you could get the sensitivity to all 3 by figuring out the variance of f, as function of the variances of the 3. To make it easy linearized the equation for f, wrt the 3 variables, and then replace the 3 variables and their coefficients with coefficient and sigma squared for each, and plus in for each sigma the error expected of each. The equation for summing sigma squared is what any statistics book will tell you what it is when a random variable is the linear sum of others, and each can be considered Gaussian distributed.

You do need estimate or spec for the errors of each of the 3 variables. I think humidity will have a negligible contribution.

Comment: Note that while the error is 0.01% relative to the absolute frequency, the error in the _shift_ is almost 20% of that shift (4/20, roughly).